# Why does GIT ignore tmp folders?

Tags: git, tmp

Just noticed (after 4 years) that git seems to automatically ignore any tmp folder in any subdirectory of my project. Now, I'm quite happy with that but it worries me: are there other things it's ignoring by default?

My .gitignore does have a line like:

```
tmp/
```

However if I remove that entry all my tmp folders are still ignored.

There are no other mentions of 'tmp' in my .gitignore
I've looked in other files e.g. '.git/info/exclude' and '.git/config' but can't see anything there.
I've also looked at:

```
git config --get core.excludesfile
```

It returns nothing.

Comment: only .ignore content are ignored by default

Comment: Is there anything in the folder? GIT does not track folders. It tracks files. If the folder is empty there is nothing to track

Comment: @Liam Yes there's a file in there that's not ignored (the parent folder has files of same extension that are under git control).

Comment: I've just tried it locally and it's not ignored. So the this question is based on a false premise and therefore can't be answered

Comment: `git status` shows directories named `tmp` as untracked.  That's not ignored, it's just untracked.

Comment: @William Pursell Yes, but "git add" ignores it so it can't be tracked or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Ignores *what*? You can't add folders to git, like Liam said. You can only add files. So if you try to `git add` a file in the tmp folder, does it not work?

Comment: @Liam yeh, you're right I'm just making it up.

Comment: @guy incognito There's are files in there "git add ." ignores them but not if I rename the folder to say "teemp".

Comment: Does `git check-ignore -v <ignored_file_path>` print anything?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks to "Guy Incognito" I tried:

```
git add bla/bla/tmp/bla.txt
```

And that gave the message that, that path is ignored by one of my .gitignore files.
So I removed the "tmp/" from my .gitignore and indeed now git does not ignore bla.txt (`git status` shows it and `git add .` adds it). Some 'tmp' folders are still "ignored" but indeed as people have pointed out (Liam) these are empty.

It seems that a line like:

```
bla/
```

in a .gitignore will ignore all folders named "bla" (and their content) in any subdirectory. I thought it would just ignore any top-level "bla" folder.

Was so surprised by this that I looked it up and it is i.m.o a bit "subtle":

```
bla/
```

in your .gitignore will ignore all folders called "bla" in the directory the .gitignore is in and all of it's sub-folders. So `bla` and `foo/bla` will both be ignored. However

```
bar/bla/
```

in your .gitignore, will only ignore `bar/bla` but not for example `foo/bar/bla`.

B.t.w. if you want to ignore just a top level folder you can use:

```
/bla/
```

Comment: If a file is being ignored, `git check-ignore -v` will find the specific directive that is causing this, which is pretty handy sometimes. It doesn't help if you're trying to figure out why some `.gitignore` file or line *isn't* working, though.

Answer (score 0):

Git never sees empty folders in working directory. To add a temporary folder, it must contain any file tracked by Git. If you wish to ship the temporary folder so that it's available right after git-clone, put an empty mindless file to the folder. Common name for such file is `.gitkeep`. It means nothing to Git but allows the latter to store the folder in repository.

```
touch tmp/.gitkeep
git add tmp/.gitkeep
```